# How to handle endpoint failure in wso2esb and wso2dss

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I created proxy services using wso2dss for data insertion, so services working fine I am quite happy with this. But while any data duplication errors occurred in wso2dss I need to handle it in wso2esb so I kept this property in wso2esb for dss level error handle:

```
 <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
```

So its working fine I am getting 50000 code using this I am able to handle error while this error my esb showing this message:

```
[2014-03-07 11:22:40,778] INFO - LogMediator To: /services/GeoLocationInsertion, MessageID: urn:uuid:b51629e2-934e-4227-8f50-65fd9f719b8e, Direction: request, userid = -1212807836, username = sa|214057357158656, password = sa
[2014-03-07 11:22:40,783] INFO - LogMediator To: /services/ServiceLogin, MessageID: urn:uuid:1967bde1-d820-46f9-957d-55fbb6f7ea9e, Direction: request, usercode = sa, clientid = 214057357158656
[2014-03-07 11:22:40,833] INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:24aea5ed-f4e2-4214-809b-b3101031edf7, Direction: response, faisal = true
[2014-03-07 11:22:40,838] INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:42a17360-cd04-43bc-83ef-1f53b639de11, Direction: response, kk = true
[2014-03-07 11:22:40,853] WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : endpoint_71f1485e740c2b97ec407fe4d3bf86929122480f208b6642 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2014-03-07 11:22:40,853] WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : endpoint_71f1485e740c2b97ec407fe4d3bf86929122480f208b6642 - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Fri Mar 07 11:23:10 IST 2014
[2014-03-07 11:22:40,856] INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:42a17360-cd04-43bc-83ef-1f53b639de11, Direction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 500000, ERROR_MESSAGE = null
[2014-03-07 11:22:40,857] INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:42a17360-cd04-43bc-83ef-1f53b639de11, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ResponseJSON><Body><Data><Exception>duplicate key value violates or The system is attempting to access an inactive service </Exception></Data></Body><Status>500000</Status></ResponseJSON></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Above error message means my endpoint gone into suspend mode after 30sec it will automatically in active mode.

If any user tries on the same time he is unable to insert his correct data and he is losing the data due to endpoint nonavailability. So how we can keep endpoint in active mode?
If any other error will come this issue is not raising:

```
[2014-03-07 11:22:40,853] WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : endpoint_71f1485e740c2b97ec407fe4d3bf86929122480f208b6642 - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Fri Mar 07 11:23:10 IST 2014
```

So how would I do this?
If I remove the property I am unable to handle DSS level message and I am getting error like this even my user not getting any response:

```
[2014-03-07 11:20:51,816] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFault
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.getFault(SOAPBodyImpl.java:120)
at org.apache.synapse.util.POXUtils.convertSOAPFaultToPOX(POXUtils.java:46)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:91)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:308)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:92)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:232)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:443)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:166)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:222)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

So that 30sec are so important, it causes my client's data loss. How could I avoid this endpoint failure?

The actual error in wso2dss is:

```
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "deviceid" is of type bigint but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 81

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.getReader(DSOMDataSource.java:116)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:225)
    ... 41 more
```

I handle it in wso2esb fault and working fine also but endpoint failure is uncatchble

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure your DSS endpoint's suspension behavior in the ESB, please refer to the [Endpoint Error Handling](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Endpoint+Error+Handling) documentation.

If you drop the FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT property, you should still be able to handle a soap fault from your DSS response in the out sequence of an ESB proxy.

Answer (score 0):

yo can disable that config with this configuration in your endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<endpoint>
  <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService">
    <timeout>
      <duration>30000</duration>
      <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
    </timeout>
    <suspendOnFailure>
      <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
      <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
      <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
    </suspendOnFailure>
    <markForSuspension>
      <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
    </markForSuspension>
  </address>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this error myself and it was terrible to identify it and find a way to work with it. It seems there is a bug in older versions of WSO2 ESB (we have this problem with version 4.8.1) when dealing with a returned soap fault.

You can see the answer of @JorgeInfanteOsorio to disable the endpoint suspension, but you will need an workaround for the "Uncaught exception" issue. What I found is that it is possible to retrieve the parameters from the fault message and then "clear" the current payload, so any subsequent calls wont return the exception issue.

Example:

```
<!--
    After we call a webservice on DSS or other webservice we check if the message contains a fault message
-->
<property xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
         name="return_fault"
         expression="/s:Envelope/s:Body/s:Fault"/>

<filter source="boolean(get-property('return_payzen_fault'))" regex="true">
    <then>
    <!--
        There is a fault message on the payload...
    -->

        <!--
            Retrieve the information from the fault message. How you will access it and which information you will retrieve may be different depending if the answer comes from a third part webservice or from your own DSS.
        -->
        <property xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" name="code" expression="/s:Envelope/s:Body/s:Fault/s:Code/s:faultcode"/>
        <property xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" name="code" expression="/s:Envelope/s:Body/s:Fault/s:Code/s:faultstring"/>

        <!--
             Clear the payload containing the fault message
          -->
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                  <soapenv:Body/>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>

        <!--
             Now you can proceed and process the message as usual without getting the exception. You may probably use the parameters stored in the properties at the beginning to determine which error occured and what you are going to do next.
        -->

    </then>
</filter>
<!--
    There is no fault message, you can proceed with the message processing here.
-->
```